# Dynamic number of inputs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have problem with dynamic number of radio input in array like that

```
Color:<br>
<label><input type="radio" name="params[54]" value="21">Blue</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="params[54]" value="38">Yellow</label>
Size:<br>
<label><input type="radio" name="params[12]" value="32">S</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="params[12]" value="44">M</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="params[12]" value="58">L</label>
```

It could not be only Color and Size and it shoud have more than two or three inputs. 
I use VueJS Component.

```
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            params: {}
        }
    },
    methods:{
        update: function(){
            // here I want use params
        }
    }
}
```

I need watch change input and get params object witch one are selected like:

```
{
    54: 21,
    12: 44
}
```

In my old jQuery code I do this like that

```
$("input[type=radio]").on("change", function(){
        var selected = {};
        $("input:checked").each(function(a, b){
            selected[$(b).data("param-id")] = $(b).data("value-id");
        });
});
```

But in this I seriously don't know how can I do this in Vue. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I sove it by passing list of params

```
var params = JSON.parse(this.$attrs.params);
for(var key in params){
    this.$set(this.params, key, 0);
    this.$watch("params."+key, function(){
        this.update();
    });
}
```

And adding v-model to input

```
<label>
    <input
    :checked="params[54] == 21"
    v-model="params[54]"
    type="radio"
    name="params[54]"
    v-bind:value="21"
    >
    Blue
</label>
```

Now I can use this.attributes to get object of selected params.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do. But I would use `v-for` and `v-model` to create the select boxes and to track the selection. Is something like in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/zoo4L8x8/) working for you?

Comment: No, its not working, because I need something like onChange event on these inputs and I dont know how to create watch for something dynamical like this.

Comment: You could add `@change="changedSize($event, product.id)` to the select tag of size selection to get an event at every selection change and then use the `event.target.value` to get the value of the selection and use the passed id to add it to your selection.

Comment: Problem with @change is method must be defined in Vue instance not in Component, so I can't change component data easily.

Comment: You can also define the @change in component if you're using [`$emit`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit) to pass it to a listener method of parent component or by using Vuex.